zramctl showing incorrect values
I have setup a zram with the zram-generator package on a Manjaro (stable) install. I don't have any other swap configured. When I run the zramctl command, the given values are significantly lower than what swap uses (see command outputs below).
zramctl, where DATA is the size of the uncompressed data on the ramdisk, COMPR is the compressed data and TOTAL is the current size of the ramdisk:
$ zramctl 
NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA COMPR TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram0 zstd         31,3G 10,2G  3,2G  3,4G      12 [SWAP]

Output of swapon:
$ swapon
NAME       TYPE       SIZE  USED PRIO
/dev/zram0 partition 31,3G 14,8G  100

And output of free (it's also interesting that it cuts off the decimal part on used, but not relevant here):
$ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31Gi        24Gi       2,5Gi       314Mi       6,0Gi       6,4Gi
Swap:           31Gi        14Gi        16Gi

/proc/meminfo contains some relevant info as well:
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep swap
Zswap:            993724 kB
Zswapped:        4745548 kB

What is strange here is that if I subtract this Zswapped value from used swap, I get approximately the zramctl report DATA value
My question is - even though swapping seems to work fine - why is this the case? Is it a problem with zramctl?
